# php mysql view total amount from the database

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database

I want to echo sum of Amound row with student id but I have another column which is call "type" (it should be have only Admission, Installment, Other).

so when I want to echo it should be show the total of the amount column but not included (Other from "Type")

[image]
I want to echo that red box total with particulate student id

Comment: SUM, GROUP BY and WHERE, look those up

Answer (score 0):

```
select sum(Amount) as total_amount 
from `table_name` 
where `Type` in('Admission', 'Installment', 'Other') group by Student_ID
```

Comment: My code is https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/63427474/01.png

output is https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/63427474/02.png

But the data from the database is https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/63427474/3.png

so the output not come that much which is too much and wrong as well

Comment: group by Student_ID = '$Student_id' is wrong u need to use as `Where Student_ID = '$Student_id'` and remove group by Student_ID

Comment: Again getting error message https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/63427474/4.png

https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/63427474/5.png

Comment: Oh U can not have 2 `WHERE`,  the query should be `where Type in ('Admission', 'Installment', 'Other') AND  Student_ID = '$Student_id' `